# Unexpected value 'jqxGridComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular

The screen just says "loading.." and this error is shown in the console.

> compiler.es5.js:16156 Uncaught Error: Unexpected value
>   'jqxGridComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a
>   @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
>       at ZoneAwareError (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports
>   (addScript.js:9), :2571:38)
>       at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1694)
>       at compiler.es5.js:15590
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata
>   (compiler.es5.js:15572)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._loadModules
>   (compiler.es5.js:26958)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.*compileModuleAndComponents
>   (compiler.es5.js:26931)
>       at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync
>   (compiler.es5.js:26860)
>       at PlatformRef*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.*bootstrapModuleWithZone
>   (core.es5.js:4535)
>       at PlatformRef*.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule
>   (core.es5.js:4521)
>       at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (main.ts:10)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap e79c7d6b3fb8625d1438:54)
>       at Object.6 (main.bundle.js:6516)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap e79c7d6b3fb8625d1438:54)
>       at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap e79c7d6b3fb8625d1438:25)

Below is how am using them

App.module.ts

```js
import { jqxGridComponent } from 'ng2jqxcomponents/angular_jqxgrid';

@NgModule({
 imports: [],


 declarations: [jqxGridComponent],
 bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

examplepage.component.ts file

```js
/** jqWidgets imports */
import 'wrapperjqxcore';
import 'wrapperjqxgridui';
import 'wrapperjqxgrid';
/** jqxGrid Angular Plugin */
import { jqxGridComponent } from 'ng2jqxcomponents/angular_jqxgrid';
@Component({
 })
...
```

Wrapper is a wrapper that a team has developed at my workplace which we just include in package.json like below and go on with the development.

package.json -

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@fgo-/wrapperclient3": "^3.1.3",
```

Comment: From a glance at this documentation https://www.jqwidgets.com/angular-components-documentation/documentation/angular-cli/angular-cli-jqxgrid.htm I would say you might either have the wrong version installed (your package.json code snippet does not state any jqWidgets) or you forgot to add the source files to the `"include"` block in your tsconfig.json

Comment: Formatted error + added code formatting

Comment: @masterfloda I will try to add the versions and include block in some time, thankyou for your input. Im sure i have all those properly added, but let me add those to my question.

Comment: @BrandonMinnick, can you please elaborate your answer? I did not get you :)